# Can the interruption of a browser download be caused by the Wi-Fi dongle hardware?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, browser, download

I used Linux Mint 19.1 (Tessa) on my computer, and had **no problems** with browser downloads (Firefox). Then, my HDD crashed, and I replaced it with a small SSD and installed Windows 10 (currently on build 19041.329). Therefore, my whole system was fresh since five days ago. Now, my browser downloads get interrupted (and fail) on both Edge 83.0.478.54 (Official build) (64-bit) (Chromium-based) and Firefox 77.0.1 (64-bit).

Is it possible that my Wi-Fi dongle (a Panda PAU05 300Mbps Wireless 802.11n USB Adapter) could be the problem? I just assume that I should buy another dongle, to test it out.

Comment: Make sure you have the most current Windows 10 driver for the adapter. The interruption issue is not due to Windows 10 or Edge Chromium. I have all that here with an Intel Wireless Adapter.

Comment: Are you saying that I should install the Windows driver, even though Panda [says that the adapter is plug and play on Windows 10, and that I shouldn't need to install the driver myself](http://www.pandawireless.com/Drivers%20%7C%20Panda%20Wireless.html)?

Comment: I would certainly try that. Hardware needs the driver for the OS installed and you said you installed Windows 10 on the SSD

Comment: [Here is a screenshot of the driver,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcvEu.jpg) which I assume Windows 10 installed. Is it possible for the adapter to work occasionally (like it does), without the correct driver?

Comment: That is a generic Microsoft driver.  Can you try the driver the card manufacturer provides?

Comment: I ran their Mediatek InstallShield Wizard to install the driver, but I don't see a difference in the Properties dialogue box for the device. (Would a system restart be necessary?) I tried the 2GB download in Firefox a few times, and those attempts failed. I usually use Firefox, but Edge downloaded the file now. Edge did give the download problem a few days ago.

Comment: Since I just managed to download the 2GB file I wanted, the problem isn't urgent anymore, but I can comment here again if Edge doesn't work in future, to let you know.

Comment: Just a random thought, but maybe there's some strange USB power management options in Windows that is causing the problem. I honestly don't think it's likely, but it may explain why the dongle worked well in Linux but not in Windows.